# how to remove a html tag using Razor

Tags: razor

hey guys I have  tag which I want to remove it with razor,posiible?

```
 <div id="branding">
        <img alt="stl" src="@Url.Content("pic"/>
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
      ....remove the above <img> tag
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't remove it, you just don't output it in the first place:

```
<div id="branding">
    @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) <!-- Note the ! here -->
    {
        <img alt="stl" src="@Url.Content("pic")/>
    }
```

Comment: thanks it works,but generaly is there any command to remove a tag using razor?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be removing tags. If you are thinking that way, then you probably need to change how you think Razor is working.